# How to get selected items from a QListView which uses custom QAbstractListModel in C++

Tags: c++, list, qt, mvvm, model

I have created a custom list model following this guide [Creating a cusotm model for a QListView](https://cozic.net/pogopixels/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-model-for-a-qlistview-in-qt/index.html). I am able to show a list of custom objects (such as the Employee as in the example) but I don't know how to retrieve back the selected ones (can I retrieve back the "linked" objects directly?).

Maybe do I have to do something with this command:

```
myLV->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
```

But I don't really know how to retrieve back the original custom objects.

[EDIT]

So far I have solved retrieving back the object adding a custom method inside my custom list model:

```
Employee* MyEmployeeListModel::getAtSelectedIndex(const QModelIndex& index){
    return employees_.at(index.row());
}
```

And then calling this on the main window:

```
QModelIndexList selectedRows;
QItemSelectionModel * selmodel = ui->employeesLV->selectionModel();
selectedRows = selmodel->selectedRows();

MyEmployeeListModel* currModel = dynamic_cast <MyEmployeeListModel*>(ui->employeesLV->model());

for (const QModelIndex & index : selectedRows){
    Employee* item=currModel->getAtSelectedIndex(index);
    if (item) {
        // do something with the item
    }
}
```

Now what I am willing to know is if this is the real best practice or not.

Comment: Can you give an example for those objects? You could pass an id via custom role, or the whole object. (Requires Q_DECLARE_METATYPE/qRegisterMetatype())

Comment: Consider a simple employee class with an id, name and surname. In the list I have exactly the same code as the example that I have linked. The list is showing the surname. When selected a list of employees, I would liek to retrieve back the whole information for each selected employee.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code with a QTreeView (ui->treeMessages), but this should work with a QListView as well:

```
            QModelIndexList selectedRows;
            QItemSelectionModel * selmodel = ui->treeMessages->selectionModel();
            selectedRows = selmodel->selectedRows();

            for (const QModelIndex & index : selectedRows)
            {
                const QModelIndex sourceIndex = m_sortFilterModel->mapToSource(index);
                ItemData * item = sourceIndex.internalPointer();
                if (item) { 
                    // do something
                }

            }
```